# What statistical method to correct systematic error in the output of a economic optimization model?

Tags: modeling, forecasting, optimization, bias, filter

I am working with an economic optimization model which attempts to model the dynamics of a certain commodity market (prices, quantities, production etc.) for different frequencies (monthly, quarterly, yearly). The model works well in many respects, but one can see that the model output of the price is systematically wrong. Here is a schematic drawing:

[image: Plot 1]
As you can see, the model output is systematically underestimating the historical data in terms of up and down movements. The simulated price behaves too sluggish when compared to historical data.

(edit: The model is not a statistical model. It is an fundamental economic optimization model: Every consumer and producer is optimizing her profit under certain constraints individually. The model is can be described in a mathematical way as an mixed-complementary problem. It is written in the software GAMS and contains thousands of lines code.)

My questions:

1. What statistical method can I use to correct the systematic error in the model output?
2. The model also produces a forecast. Is there a way to correct the anticipated bias in the forecast?

(I am working with R and MATLAB)

Thank you in advance

Comment: you could try arimax dynamic transfer function models.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you plase describe a bit more precisely how to apply this method to my kind of problem?

Answer (score 3):

The model output does *not* underestimate systematically the historical data: it underpredicts/underestimates high prices and overpredicts low prices. *This is exactly what we should expect from a, say, optimal in terms of Mean Squared-Error, estimation/forecast function to do* : Optimal forecasts "represent a shrinkage towards the mean", and have *lower variability* than the actual data.

This can be easily shown as follows:

Denote $X$ the actual series $f$ its forecast and $e$ the forecast error, and $X = f+e$.
If $f$ is MSE-optimal, it is efficient, and so "no information is left unexplored", which in technical terms means that $f$ is uncorrelated with $e$, and also, that no systematic error occurs, so $E(e) =0$. We have

$$\operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{Var}(f)+\operatorname{Var}(e)$$

which necessarily implies that 
$$\operatorname{Var}(f) < \operatorname{Var}(X)$$

Such kind of forecasts/estimations are optimal "on average" and "in the long run", and may tend not to work very well with high-frequency data, or when you are after short-term optimization...

Perhaps one could visually "detect" the possibility that the model output could exhibit the same variability but be shifted higher along the vertical axis, (i.e. that there may be a downward bias in estimating the long-term mean of the process), but this is just a matter of having a constant term in the estimation function, nothing more...

I believe that you can see that your question is very general for us to provide a truly useful answer. You will have to provide much more specific information, about the characteristics of the real data you try to estimate/forecast, and about the estimation/forecast methods that you are using.

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
The model is not a statistical model. It is an fundamental economic optimization model: Every consumer and producer is optimizing her profit under certain constraints individually.  The model can be described in a mathematical way as an mixed-complementary problem. It is written in the software GAMS and contains thousands of lines code. The model does not involve any statistical or econometric method. I am sorry, I have not clarified this exactly.

Comment: Then CV is not the website to ask the question. If your model is deterministic, i.e. it assumes that the real world behavior is described without any source of randomness, how do you think statistical concepts could help you?